# Codepen working on HTML not working on ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm facing a problem while integrating a project from codepen into ASP.NET. While I download the project and test it on atom it works perfectly, but when I try to transfer it to ASP.NET (copy paste) it stops working, it just switch between log in / register without moving. I'm new to ASP.NET so maybe I'm missing something... It gives a green warning on the double `<html>` and `<body>` tags maybe the problem is there, I just don't know how to fix it. Any help is welcome thanks on advance.

The original codepen: [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/mrtial/pen/RRGOad)

Note: only edit I made was adding / on non closing <> elements because ASP.NET told me to.

```js
var $loginMsg = $('.loginMsg'),
  $login = $('.login'),
  $signupMsg = $('.signupMsg'),
  $signup = $('.signup'),
  $frontbox = $('.frontbox');

$('#switch1').on('click', function () {
    $loginMsg.toggleClass("visibility");
    $frontbox.addClass("moving");
    $signupMsg.toggleClass("visibility");

    $signup.toggleClass('hide');
    $login.toggleClass('hide');
})

$('#switch2').on('click', function () {
    $loginMsg.toggleClass("visibility");
    $frontbox.removeClass("moving");
    $signupMsg.toggleClass("visibility");

    $signup.toggleClass('hide');
    $login.toggleClass('hide');
})

setTimeout(function () {
    $('#switch1').click()
}, 1000)

setTimeout(function () {
    $('#switch2').click()
}, 3000)
```

```css
body{
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container{
  /*border:1px solid white;*/
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-flex;
}
.backbox{
  background-color: #404040;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  top:50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.frontbox{
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  transition: right .8s ease-in-out;
}

.moving{
  right:45%;
}

.loginMsg, .signupMsg{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.loginMsg .title,
.signupMsg .title{
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.loginMsg p,
.signupMsg p {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.textcontent{
  color:white;
  margin-top:65px;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.loginMsg button,
.signupMsg button {
  background-color: #404040;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color:white;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding:10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* front box content*/
.login, .signup{
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.login h2,
.signup h2 {
  color: #35B729;
  font-size:22px;
}

.inputbox{
  margin-top:30px;
}
.login input,
.signup input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login button,
.signup button{
  background-color: #35B729;
  border: none;
  color:white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  right:30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Fade In & Out*/
.login p {
  cursor: pointer;
  color:#404040;
  font-size:15px;
}

.loginMsg, .signupMsg{
  /*opacity: 1;*/
  transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
}

.visibility{
  opacity: 0;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    
     <link href="stylelogin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  

</head>

<body>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="container">
    <div class="backbox">
      <div class="loginMsg">
        <div class="textcontent">
          <p class="title">Don't have an account?</p>
          <p>Sign up to save all your graph.</p>
          <button id="switch1">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="signupMsg visibility">
        <div class="textcontent">
          <p class="title">Have an account?</p>
          <p>Log in to see all your collection.</p>
          <button id="switch2">LOG IN</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- backbox -->

    <div class="frontbox">
      <div class="login">
        <h2>LOG IN</h2>
        <div class="inputbox">
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="  EMAIL"/>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="  PASSWORD"/>
        </div>
        <p>FORGET PASSWORD?</p>
        <button>LOG IN</button>
      </div>

      <div class="signup hide">
        <h2>SIGN UP</h2>
        <div class="inputbox">
          <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="  FULLNAME"/>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="  EMAIL"/>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="  PASSWORD"/>
        </div>
        <button>SIGN UP</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- frontbox -->
  </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
  

    <script src="jslogin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where are you calling you Jquery code in asp.net?

Comment: Try first to remove the second <body> and both </body></html> that are before the <script src="jslogin.js"></script>
Then, tell us which error your browser displays in the debug console (F12).

Comment: @Webruster I don't really know it's something I copied from codepen (see link)

Comment: @Booster2ooo I'll try and let you know thanks

Comment: @Booster2ooo Is it possible that there aren't any errors? I don't get one but it still doesn't work though

Comment: @Booster2ooo I answered my own question so you could see the screenshot

Comment: @LucasVerhoest is it working?

Comment: @LucasVerhoest it seems something similar to your codepend example is displayed and there is no error in the console, so, may we assume it's working ? If not, try to be as specific as possible in describing the problem(s) you face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `e.preventDefault` to your functions to avoid jQuery triggering things it doesn't have to do.

```
$('#switch1').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $loginMsg.toggleClass("visibility");
   $frontbox.addClass("moving");
   $signupMsg.toggleClass("visibility");

   $signup.toggleClass('hide');
   $login.toggleClass('hide');
})

$('#switch2').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $loginMsg.toggleClass("visibility");
   $frontbox.removeClass("moving");
   $signupMsg.toggleClass("visibility");

   $signup.toggleClass('hide');
   $login.toggleClass('hide');
})
```

I got this working in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6425g1m5/), so please check it out, try it on your code and let us know if it works or not.

Hope it helps you.